# How can I remove unnecessary white background from gif?

Tags: android, kotlin, gif, android-glide

I got unnecessary white background with square box while loading with Glide.

Below are the code

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/loading"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_loader"/>
```

Below is the fragment that loading the image :
class LoaderFragment(private val msg:String?) : DialogFragment() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val v = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.dialog_waiting,container,false)


    val ivLogo = v.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivLogo)


        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.bg_loader_te)
            .fitCenter()
            .apply(
                RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.bg_loader_te)
                    .centerCrop()
            )
            .into(ivLogo)
   

    return v
}
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
}
```

}

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Also I tried the below code

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_loader"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this using the below code

```
this.dialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false) this.dialog?.setCancelable(false) this.dialog?.setOnKeyListener { dialog, keyCode, event -> keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK } this.dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of <[ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton)> use <[ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView)>.

Comment: Already tried that too @Taranmeet Singh

Comment: @GreeshmaS have you checked if the gif is originally transparent or it already has a white background

Comment: yes the gif is originally transparent.while opening in chrome and in app it showing the white background.And while opening in photos no background @Taranmeet Singh

Comment: the Glide is loading inside a Fragment that extends to a DialogFragment

Comment: t @GreeshmaS have you tried loading the same image in a simple activity or a sample project also can you add the url of this image I will try in a sample project

Comment: yes.Now this is fixed.I used the below code                                                                                       this.dialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    this.dialog?.setCancelable(false)
    this.dialog?.setOnKeyListener { dialog, keyCode, event -> keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK }
    this.dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

Comment: @GreeshmaS if you have an answer kindly add the same as answer to your question and accept it that can help anyone in future.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

with

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: no change@navylover